# Dynamic char array with null termination

Tags: c, string, pointers, dynamic-memory-allocation

i wanted to create a function that can dynamically append a char array, here's my current code:

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

void append_string(char** string, unsigned int* len, const char append_val) {
  if (*string == NULL) {
    *string = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 2); // allocate memory for `append_val` and the null character
    **string = append_val;
    *(*string + 1) = '\0';

    *len = 1; // i decided to exclude the null character from the string length
    return;
  }

  *string = (char*)realloc(*string, sizeof(char) * (*len + 2)); // 2 is for the null character and `append_val`
  *(*string + *len++) = append_val;
  *(*string + *len) = '\0';
}

int main(void)
{
  char input = 0;
  char* str = NULL;
  unsigned int str_len = 0;

  while (input = getch()) {
    append_string(&str, &str_len, input);
    printf("%s", str);
  }

  return 0;
}
```

My function works well if the `string` argument is `NULL`, but if `string` is not `NULL` the program crashes. Ive been thinking about this for a while but i can't really find the solution to this problem, need some help :/

Comment: `*len++` is interpreted as `*(len++)`. You want `(*len)++`

Comment: @Barmar wow, i expected it to be some logical error but it turned out to be a small syntax mistake. thank you for the help :)

Comment: `while (input = getch()) { ... }` is going to loop a _long_  time - _forever_ once `getch()` returns `EOF`.

Comment: yes i know that, i wanted it to be an infinite loop but i felt like its more elegant than `while (1) { input = getch(); ... }`